# How to infer the eigenvalue distribution from matrix where each entry has a known Gaussian distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

## Problem

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $X_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{ij}, \sigma_{ij}^2 I)$

Find the eigenvalue distribution using whatever you can.

## Background

In my field, I have a Bayesian inference framework that will obtain the $X$ distribution, but what we really need is the eigenvalue distribution of the matrix $X$.

## Question

1. Is this problem well defined?
2. Is the only way to infer it through sampling in such **high dimensional** space and then for each realization of the matrix, do the eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: [On the spectral distribution of Gaussian random matrices](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/jian-feng.yao/publi/DelyonYao.pdf) (pdf)